# To Update 100 Columns in a single query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to update a table which contains more than 100 columns in it. I'm using an update query to do this. My problem is instead of specifying all the 100 columns in an update query is it possible to update without the column names.

**Query:**

```
Update tbleName set Col1='',Col2='',Col3='',.....Coln='';
commit;
```

Is there any possibility to update this table columns without specifying 100 columns.

**Note:**

This table contains more than 120 columns but I need to update 100 columns .

Sorry, I forgot mention this, I need to update first 100 columns only!!!

Thanks in advance!

--Ranga

Comment: No. You have to specify the column names.

Comment: How would the database know which 100 columns you want to update if you don't specify the column names?

Comment: Why is this even an issue?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considered little application thats reads column names from this table and prepares update query? I think you could even use stored procedures for that.

Answer (score 2):

No you `must` have to specify which column value you want to modify in update statement.

Answer (score 0):

120 columns? Ouch, that's a pain. You could build up a sql string and just execute it.